# calico-policy-container on the worker node is on a restart loop. how can i check why?

Tags: kubernetes, coreos, calico

I have two coreos stable machines (with latest stable version installed) to test Kubernetes. i installed kubernetes 1.5.1 using the script from https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/tree/master/multi-node/generic and patched it with https://github.com/kfirufk/coreos-kubernetes-multi-node-generic-install-script.

I installed controller script on one and worker script on the other. `kubectl get nodes` shows both servers.

`kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system` shows that `calico-policy-controller-2j5dn` restarts a lot. in the worker server I do see that `calico-policy-controller` restarts a lot. any idea how to investigate this issue further?

how can I check why it restarts? are there any logs for this container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`kubectl logs --previous $id —namespace=kube-system`

i added `--previous` because when the controller restart it has a different random characters appended to it.

in my case that `kube-policy-controller` what started on one server, and requested the etcd2 certificates that where generated on a different server.